# How to show text if no posts from query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WordPress post type, and want to make so if there are no posts in the query to display, it shows a message of saying no posts were found, I've tried a few suggestions but nothing seems to be working so far.

Full Code of the relevant section:

```
 <?php
            $k=0;
            $args = array(
                'post_type'=>'portfolios',
                'posts_per_page'=>5,
                'order'=>'DESC'
                );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            while($the_query->have_posts()):$the_query->the_post();
            $k++;
            if($k==1){
                $color= 'gray';
            }else if($k==2){
                $color= 'blue';                
            }else if($k==3){
                $color= 'green';                
            }else if($k==4){
                $color= 'light-blue';                
            }else if($k==5){
                $color= 'yellow';              
            }

        ?>
            <div itemprop="exampleOfWork" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                <div class="portfolio-holder">
                <?php
                    if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'singleport',true);
                ?>
                    <figure><a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url[0];?>" alt="Portfolio image" /></a></figure>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    <figure><a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/assets/images/noimage.jpg" alt="No image" /></a></figure>
                <?php } ?>
                    <h6 itemprop="name"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
                    <span itemprop="genre"><?php the_field('name');?></span>
                    <div class="transparentbg <?php echo $color; ?>">
                    <?php
                        $image = get_field('logo');
                        if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                        <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="logo" />
                        </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="info">
                            <img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/assets/images/port-hover-bg.png" alt="Port hover bg" /><br />
                            <img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/assets/images/search-icon.png" height="20" width="20" alt="Search icon">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How can we make it so, if there's no posts, it echo's a message?

Comment: so if `$k = 0` there are no posts?

Comment: @Huey Well, I tried adding an else if, for when k = 0, but that doesn't work, for whatever reason that may be.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check -

```
if (!empty($the_query->have_posts())) {
   while(...) {...}
} else {
   echo "No Posts!";
}
```

Comment: Gives unexpected '}' on line 45.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php
                $k=0;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'=>'portfolios',
                    'posts_per_page'=>5,
                    'order'=>'DESC'
                    );
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if($the_query->have_posts()):
                    while($the_query->have_posts()):$the_query->the_post();
                        $k++;
                        if($k==1){
                            $color= 'gray';
                        }else if($k==2){
                            $color= 'blue';                
                        }else if($k==3){
                            $color= 'green';                
                        }else if($k==4){
                            $color= 'light-blue';                
                        }else if($k==5){
                            $color= 'yellow';              
                        }

                    ?>
                        <div itemprop="exampleOfWork" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                            <div class="portfolio-holder">
                            <?php
                                if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'singleport',true);
                            ?>
                                <figure><a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url[0];?>" alt="Portfolio image" /></a></figure>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                <figure><a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/assets/images/noimage.jpg" alt="No image" /></a></figure>
                            <?php } ?>
                                <h6 itemprop="name"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
                                <span itemprop="genre"><?php the_field('name');?></span>
                                <div class="transparentbg <?php echo $color; ?>">
                                <?php
                                    $image = get_field('logo');
                                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                                    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="logo" />
                                    </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="info">
                                        <img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/assets/images/port-hover-bg.png" alt="Port hover bg" /><br />
                                        <img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );?>/assets/images/search-icon.png" height="20" width="20" alt="Search icon">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                else:
                    echo "Your message goes here";
                endif;
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Adding if condition will do it.

Comment: What is your line 45 and 46 ? I have just edited the code that you provided. So if you have not provided full code then you need to make change accordingly.

Comment: On Line 46 it is: ?> and line 45 is blank

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

You want to use WP Query class for fetching a particular type of posts ( based on custom fields ), and if it returns no posts at all, it should display a message.

**Solution**

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

Where "$args" is your list of parameters for WP_Query constructor.

Now $the_query is an object of class type WP-Query. Hence it contains a function that will return whether there is any post matching your particular query. If there is at least one post, it will return True, else it will return False.

That function to check if there are any posts matching your queries is **have_posts()** .

Usage is **ObjectName->have_posts();**

in your specific case it is

**$the_query->have_posts();**

This will return true or false based on the query ( ie, arguments you supply using $arg variable ).

hence:

```
if($the_query->have_posts()) {
 //There are posts matching the query
}
else
{ 
//There are no posts matching the query
}
```

You can use the below code ( You will have to modify this, but still a good start ).

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
    'post_type'=>'portfolios',
    'posts_per_page'=>5,
    'order'=>'DESC'
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

You need to add if condition before while loop like that way:

```
<?php
    $k=0;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'portfolios',
        'posts_per_page'=>5,
        'order'=>'DESC'
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           while($the_query->have_posts()):
    // your code
            <?php endwhile;
    } else {
     echo "No data found.";
    }
    wp_reset_query();

  ?>
```